# Purpose of ALPHA_CHANGED in Android

Tags: android, android-layoutparams

In `WindowManager.LayoutParams` class there is a *constant* called `ALPHA_CHANGED`. What is the purpose of it? I can't seem to find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

The alpha value has to do with the opacity of the view (i.e., how translucent it is). ALPHA_CHANGED is used to trigger events based on a change.

Comment: Thanks. So I can use it to trigger alpha changes if there is any in window. is it right?

Comment: It's not used to change the alpha value but rather to capture a change in it triggered by something else, like a switch or a slider.

Comment: Do you have a specific use for it you are trying to figure out?

Comment: No.. I am just trying to understand concept

Comment: but how to use one?